# Object is not a Function - SuperTest

Tags: node.js, koa, supertest

I'm not sure why it's throwing this error and what exactly it's saying is not a function.

```
    'use strict';

  var koa = require("koa");
    var app = koa();
    var chai = require('chai');
    var expect = chai.expect;

    var request = require('supertest');

    describe('Feature: Car REST Endpoint', function () {

        context('Scenario: GET a Car', function () {

            var url = 'http://localhost/search/cars';

            describe('Given: the resource is accessed at the resource url' + url, function () {

                describe('Then: we receive a successful response', function(){

                    it('status code should be 200', function (done){
                        request(app)
                            .get(url)
                            .expect(200,done);
                    });
                });
```

it says it's the line .expect(200,done) but I might be wrong.

I also tried this with no luck:

```
 request(app)
                    .get(url)
                    .expect(200)
                    .end(function(err, res){
                        if (err) return done(err);
                        done()
                    });
```

I also tried `var request = require('supertest').agent(koa);`

[image]

Comment: Could you share the exact error message? What isn't a function? Could you try using console.log or debugging to grab what the object is being returned as?

Comment: I'm not even sure I know what object it's talking about.

Comment: looks like the response is undefined and is probably being checked in the expect(200) line when it tries to read the response's status code...which undefined would make sense...I want my test to simply fail, not throw a huge error like this.  Of course that endpoint isn't there yet, I have to test drive it!  but my BDD test should simply fail if the response is undefined, not throw a huge fit.

Comment: You can take it a step further and set the $DEBUG environment variable = `*`. That would show you more of what was going on. I can't say just looking at the call stack what would cause it to throw an error

Comment: I think I see your error. Can you try just setting URL to `/search/cars`

Comment: are you freakin kidding me! wtf!  that was it.  what the hell I've spent hours on this

Comment: Ain't that the way of it. When in doubt, reread the docs. That's what made me realize what you were doing wrong. :P

Comment: I have read so many docs, it's just not something I'd infer would cause such havoc

Comment: I mean IMO supertest should be smarter than this, I'm debugging supertest basically

Comment: Yeah, it'd be a cool PR to [Supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) if you added a warning if you try to pass `^http://` to `#url`

Comment: yea after spending 5 hours on this error, I think I will.  Thanks

Comment: [This](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/blob/master/index.js#L25) is the line you'd need to add to, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing `http://localhost` to `#get(url)`. Change `url` to just `/search/cars`. I've got a full repro (using express)

```
var request = require('supertest'),
express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  res.send(200, {
    name: 'tobi'
  });
});

request(app)
  .get('http://localhost/user')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Success!');
  });
```

Output:

```
    if (res.status !== status) {
           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
    at Test.assert (C:\workspace\choose-your-own\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:202:12)
    at Server.assert (C:\workspace\choose-your-own\node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:131:12)
    at Server.g (events.js:199:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at net.js:1392:10
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

When I use `/user`, I just get:

```
Success!
```

Comment: and are you always handling the error in your end() in all your tests or are you just doing (200, done) for example?

Comment: 200, done works just fine. No need to keep things complicated. This line: `request = request('http://localhost:5555');` is what made it click for me. I remembered your localhost declaration and felt like it didn't fit.